# Android viewpager......how to get a hold of the views?

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager

I'm able to build an activity with a viewpager from the various examples on the web, but can I no longer use the views as they were in the original activity?  Take for example the following:

```
public class SimpleViewPagerActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout thisIsWhatBreaks;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
            ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
            myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            myPager.setCurrentItem(2);

            thisIsWhatBreaks = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutThatsAlwaysNull);

    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            thisIsWhatBreaks.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        }
        else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            thisIsWhatBreaks.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }   
    }


    public void farLeftButtonClick(View v)
    {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Far Left Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }

    public void farRightButtonClick(View v)
    {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Far Right Elephant Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            public int getCount() {
                    return 5;
            }

            public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    int resId = 0;
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                            resId = R.layout.farleft;
                            break;
                    case 1:
                            resId = R.layout.left;
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            resId = R.layout.middle;
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            resId = R.layout.right;
                            break;
                    case 4:
                            resId = R.layout.farright;
                            break;
                    }

                    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

                    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

                    return view;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
                    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

            }

            @Override
            public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

            }

            @Override
            public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public Parcelable saveState() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

    }

}
```

I originally had the `thisIsWhatBreaks` LinearLayout in `main.xml`, but have now moved it to `farleft.xml`, which is one of the layouts inflated in the PagerAdapter.

Therefore, I can no longer use 
`LinearLayout thisIsWhatBreaks = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutThatsAlwaysNull);`
to assign value to the LinearLayout.  Where and how do I do this?

How could I once again assign value to the LinearLayout so that it can be modified in the OnConfurationChanged() method as shown within this activity class?  I keep getting nullpointerexceptions all over my activity now that I've moved most of the views from main.xml to farleft.xml and can't seem to find a way to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I needed to do was move :

`thisIsWhatBreaks = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutThatsAlwaysNull);`

to the case which inflates the current layout.xml inside of instantiateItem() of the PagerAdapter.

My problem with the nullpointerexceptions was that all of my views were being acted upon in onCreate().  I had to move all of the views from onCreate() to the case statement inside of instantiateItem();

See the corrected code below....just in case anyone else runs into this problem....

```
public class SimpleViewPagerActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout thisIsWhatBreaks;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(2);

        //REMOVE THE LINEAR LAYOUT FROM BEING INSTANTIATED HERE!

}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        thisIsWhatBreaks.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        thisIsWhatBreaks.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }   
}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        public int getCount() {
                return 5;
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

          view = new View(MainHome.this);

          final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainHome.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

          switch(position){

          case 0 : 
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.farleft, null);
                    thisIsWhatBreaks= (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.layoutThatUsedToAlwaysBeNull);

                     ***Now you can modify thisIsWhatBreaks***
                    thisIsWhatBreaks.setBackgroundColor(Color.black);

              break;

          case 1: 

                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.farright, null);


              break;

          default :

              break;    
          }

         ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v,0);
         return v;  

        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
                ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

On your ViewPager, there is a method called `getCurrentItem()` which will return the current active View´s position in the ViewPager.

Now, make your own ViewPagerAdapter, make a list of views, override `instantiateItem(pagerView, position)`, add the view to the pagerView and return the view from your list, according to the position requested.

Then, you make a method called `getView(int)` which will give you the View based on the position, you get from `getCurrentItem()`.

And at last, you can now call `currentView.findViewById()`

### Also, don't forget to override `destroyItem()` where you remove the view from the PagerView.

I don't think there is any easier way of doing this, since it seems like they simply haven't provided any `getView()`, method, so you basically have to make one yourself. But in contrast, you also now have pretty good control over your views.